# arraylist, delete a variable in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I haven't used `ArrayList` much and am under the impression that to bring out variables from them i need an **enhanced for loop**.

I am trying to bring out the variable and compare their x value to another x and y value to another y value and if they match remove that variable.

So far the code i have for this method is;

```
public int detect(int x, int y){
    int count=0;
    for (EnemyShip tempEnemy:EList){
        if(x==tempEnemy.x && y==tempEnemy.y){
            EList.remove(tempEnemy);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I know the problem is with `EList.remove(tempEnemy);` and know how to accomplish this task if it were a normal for loop.

But this enhanced for loop (what my lecturer called it) has me perplexed.

So i guess my question is how can i remove the variable from the Arraylist that matches both x and y?

Comment: Can two ships have the same coordinates?

Comment: yes, two enemy ships can.

Comment: If there are two ships having the same coordinates, are both destroyed?

Comment: If the player ship is on the same co ordinates as 1 enemy ship the player wins and the enemy ship removed, if the player is on the same co ordinates as 2 enemy ships the player loses.  It would be better if the enemy ships survived if there were 2 enemy ships on the same co ordinates as the player ship, but not a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is only one ship on a coordinate, you dont need a counter.

Use this instead:

```
01 boolean strike;
02 do {
03     strike = false;
04     for (EnemyShip tempEnemy: EList) {
05         if (x==tempEnemy.x && y==tempEnemy.y) {
06             strike = true;
07             EList.remove(tempEnemy);
08             break; // We need to break here, because the line07 maybe made
09             // the list empty and cause a ConcurrentModificationException.
10             // Also: tempEnemy is not longer part of the list "EList" so we have a invalid state.
11         }
12     } 
13 } while (strike);
```

Comment: The reason for the count was that the program must have one ship destroying the other if there is only one enemy ship on x and y but if there was two enemy ships on those co ordinates than they must win.  The count was one way (i have others so if i cant use it with a solution i can change it) to detect how many ships were destroyed at that co ordinate on that turn and if it were more than one to end the game.  I have used your code and it has worked, thank you very much.

Comment: But: 2 ships can win? This rule is very important!!!! You need to write it in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Using Jdk 8 you can easily remove element safely with `removeIf` method.

```
  EList.removeIf(e-> x==e.x && y== e.y);
```

For details of `removeIf` method, read this [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Comment: Its amazing, is it `fail-safe` too?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder, Yes. It will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: In sort it does the iterator removal in single statement. +1

Comment: afaik you can skip `e->` and use `it` instead. Like this: `removeIf(x == it.x && y == it.y)`. Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

As you are iterating over list(`for-each` loops creates iterator internally) meanwhile you are changing the structure of `List` which does not supports and cause for `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Use `Iterator<E>` api for that -

```
for(Iterator iterator = EList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    tempEnemy = iterator.next();
    if(x==tempEnemy.x && y==tempEnemy.y){
         iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Note: It is recomended to use `type-safe` `List<E>` and `Iterator<E>`.

Comment: I think your answer should also explain why `Iterator` and why not `for each` loop. Afterall he is a student and OP has said he knows how to accomplish it.